# synchronic node js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, server

i am quiet new to java script and node js.
i have a problem with a simple function that i call, and it gets done more than one time.
this is my code

```
app.post('/checkGetSensorIds', function (req, res) {
  var tables=['temperature', 'pressure', 'linear_acceleration'];
  var ids= [1];
  DButils.checkAllSensorsForId(connection, 1 , tables , function(idHasSensorsInfo){
    console.log("idHasSensorsInfo is: \n" , idHasSensorsInfo);
  });
  res.end();
});


/*this function gets a user Id, and the table of all sensors the customer wants, and return true if this 
user id has information in all the sesnsor tables that were requested, otherwise returns false*/
exports.checkAllSensorsForId=  function(dbConnection, id , sensorsTables, callback){
    var sensorsTablesLength= sensorsTables.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < sensorsTables.length; i++) {
        var tableName= sensorsTables[i];
        DButils.checkSingleSensorForId(dbConnection, id, tableName, function(idHasSensorInfo){
            if(idHasSensorInfo == false){
                callback(false);
                return;
            }
            //in case user have all info in db, we get here and need to return false
            if(i == sensorsTablesLength){
                callback(true);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
};


/*this function gets a user Id, and a single sensor table, and returns true if the user has information
in the requested sensor table, otherwise returns false*/
exports.checkSingleSensorForId=  function(dbConnection , id , sensorTable, callback){
    var myQuery = 'SELECT count(*) as IdCount FROM ' + sensorTable + ' WHERE id= ' + id;
    var query = dbConnection.query(myQuery, function (err, row, result) {       
        console.log(query.sql);
        if (err) {
            console.log("checkSingleSensorForId error");
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        var count= row[0].IdCount;
        var idHasSensorInfo = (count > 0);
        callback(idHasSensorInfo);
    });
};
```

console.log("idHasSensorsInfo is: \n" , idHasSensorsInfo); is a line that invoked 3 times, while should be only once.

someone has any idea why, and what i need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
DButils.checkAllSensorsForId(connection, 1 , tables , function(idHasSensorsInfo){
    console.log("idHasSensorsInfo is: \n" , idHasSensorsInfo);
});
```

Then you have this:

```
exports.checkAllSensorsForId=  function(dbConnection, id , sensorsTables, callback){
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < sensorsTables.length; i++) {
        ...
        callback();
        ...
    }
};
```

So the callback line will be invoked as many times as you call it, which in your case is probably 3 - all it does is call the function from above, so thats why you see it invoked 3 times.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if the `callback` should be only called once, make sure its ran only once - if it should 'cancel' the `for` - add a condition to the `for` or use a `promise` to resolve whenever you are ready.